# How to create a new Google Form on drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

Creating a blank file on Google Drive works fine for several Google Apps file types like docs, spreadsheets, drawings etc.

When creating a form using the

```
application/vnd.google-apps.form
```

mimetype I just get a "bad request" response.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create those types of docs you need to use Google Apps Script.  Here is the form examples:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

Spreadsheets has a more traditional API also:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/